# Location Specific URL redirect to subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, redirect, heroku, subdomain

I'm trying to create a location specific redirect to a subdomain. My website is au.example.co and I am based in Australia. We have license partners in other locations around the world and I was hoping to create a region specific redirect. Singapore for example is sg.example.co and the U.K uk.example.co etc. I would like for a user in those countries to simply type in the url, example.co and based on where they are, be redirected to that region url. Each subdomain is it's own rails app hosted on heroku.

Answer (score 0):

There is a ruby library called [Ruby Geocoder](http://www.rubygeocoder.com/) which is useful in scenario's like this.

Direct from their website they mention the following:

> In Any Rack-Based Framework Detect Location of HTTP Request
>
> Get current user's city and country (using IP address). A location
>   method is added to the standard Rack::Request which returns a
>   Geocoder::Result object:
>
> Within Rails controller or Sinatra app
>
> city = request.location.city
>
> country = request.location.country_code

Using the above, it would be reasonable to assume you could redirect based on the country variable to the appropriate subdomain.

There is also a [RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/273-geocoder) on the subject which may be of help to you.
I also found this revised [RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/123-subdomains-revised) on subdomains which I assume may also be helpful, but I have no subscription...

Comment: Thanks for the reply @ant-fun. I've had a look at the gem and it looks useful but I'm lost as to how to implement it. The actual URL example.co has no content what so ever..so no app to use this in. It's purely there for the user to type in and then redirect to the particular rails app(subdomain of example.co) for that location. Any ideas?

Comment: I missed the part about it being it's own individual rails application sorry. If the goal is to simply redirect based on a user accessing the domain example.co,  a potential solution is to write a simple rack/sintra/rails app that handles just the routing and host it on heroku as well.